# If server using expired certificate, will NSUrlConnection will fail on request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I want to show error message that user server connection is invalid if server using expired certificate.

If we make request to server that have expired certificate, will the request fails? and `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`  delegate method called on fail?